# Issues with XML Data source

Tags: xml, birt

I have to use an XML as a data source in my report.
My xml has multiple child tags with the same name(ex. author). Please refer the XML pasted below.

```
<BookStore>
<Book>
<title>History</title>
<author>Tom</author>
<copies>10;</copies>
<price>80</price>
</Book>

<Book>
<title>Basic Mathematics</title>
<author>Roy</author>
<author>Jon</author>
<copies>5</copies>
<price>100</price>
</Book>

<Book>
<title>Java</title>
<author>Harry</author>
<author>Potter</author>
<copies>6</copies>
<price>100</price>
</Book>
</BookStore>
```

I have added a XML data source and a dataset in my report. I have made the following mappings in my XML dataset.

Row mapping: /BookStore/Book and 
Column Mapping: Mapped all the child tags

In the data set, I am getting three records, one for each of the  tag. But, the author column contains the value of only the first tag.For example, the second record contains only "Roy". The second author tag is not being recognised by the BIRT. I need to get both "Roy" & "Jon" from the second Book
element. And, I need  to get both "Harry" & "Potter" from the third Book element. Can you please let me know how to get all the values from tags with the same name into the dataset.

Appreciate your help. Please let me know how to design the XML dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In your data set you could make multiple columns such as author[1], author[2], author[3]. Then you could make a computed column that concatenates those columns together.

I do not think that XPath functions are supported in BIRT reports.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExportPDF {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException {
        String sourceFileName = "E:/ireport/issueVoucher.jasper";

        String printFileName = null;

        JRXmlDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("E:/ireport/dbsource.xml","/root/data");


        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        parameters.put("reqNo", "33434");
        parameters.put("requestorName", "Shaan");
        parameters.put("empCode", "E03030");
        parameters.put("voucherNo", "E03030");
        parameters.put("issueDate", "E03030");
        parameters.put(JRXPathQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_XML_DATA_DOCUMENT, beanColDataSource);

        try {
            printFileName = JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName, parameters, beanColDataSource);
            if (printFileName != null) {
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printFileName, "E:/sample_report.pdf");

                JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.INPUT_FILE_NAME, printFileName);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "E:/sample_report.xls");

                exporter.exportReport();
                System.out.println("done!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            }
        }catch (JRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JRXmlDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource("E:/ireport/dbsource.xml","/root/data");

Answer (score 0):

You asked for help to know how to design your XML dataset, I would rename the `author` tag to `authorFirstName` and `authorLastName` so that there is no confusion on Birt's end.